# Assign certain data to a struct with sqlite3

Tags: c, sqlite, select, struct

I've got this structure in C:

```
typedef struct{
  char *NOMBRE;
  char *APELLIDO;
  int DNI;
  char *FECHA_NACIMIENTO;
  int TELEFONO;
  char *EMAIL;
  char *DOMICILIO;
  long N_SS ;
  long N_CUENTA ;
  char *PASSWORD;
} Usuario;
```

Now that I've got the structure, I'd like to, through a SQL statement, assign certain data from table to a structure.

This is my method:

```
void bd_sacarDatosUsuario(char *user) {
  sqlite3 *db;
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  const char* data = "Callback function called";

  char sql[70];
  char sql2[10];
  char user2[10];
  strcpy(sql, "SELECT * FROM DATOS_PERSONALES WHERE DNI='");

  int rc = sqlite3_open("BD/gimud.db", &db);
  if (rc) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
  }
  strcpy(sql2, "';");
  strcpy(user2, user);
  strcat(sql, user2);
  strcat(sql, sql2);

  printf("%s\n", sql);

  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*) data, &zErrMsg);

  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);

  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Consulta creada con exito\n");
  }
  sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

How could I, in a callback function, assign the data to Usuario u? I mean:

```
Usuario u;
u.NOMBRE = argv[0]; // and so on...
```

Comment: Regrettably, there are several things wrong with this; First, don't use string concatenation to construct query strings -- use parameterized queries. Second, `sqlite3_exec()` is much better suited for query statements that don't return values; use prepared statements instead. Also, it looks like your `where` clause is using the user's name to filter rows, but it says `DNI`, which appears to be an integer (primary key?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would like to mention that the code below might not be the final code you were looking for but it could help you to understand how a callback function works.

If the callback function of the 3rd argument to `sqlite3_exec()` is not NULL, then it is invoked for each result row coming out of the evaluated SQL statements. You can pass an additional argument to the `callback` function, this is where you will have a chance to save data from the table to your so-called `Usuario` structure. The fourth argument of the `callback` serves for this purpose.

For demonstration purpose the code below does the following:

- Opens the database
- Creates a table with three columns, including ID, NAME and PASSWORD fields
- Inserts a row into the table(ID=1, NAME=PETER, PASSWORD=ORANGE)
- Allocates space for the structure
- Executes the select statement and **INVOKES THE CALLBACK()** function which stores the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Usuario{
    char *name;
    char *password;
} Usuario;

int callback(void *Usuario, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    struct Usuario *tmp = (struct Usuario *)Usuario;
    char missing[] = "MISSING";
    tmp->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[1]));
    tmp->name = argv[1] ? argv[1] : (char*)"NULL";
    tmp->password = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[2]));
    tmp->password = argv[2] ? argv[2] : (char*)"NULL";
    return 0;
}


void bd_sacarDatosUsuario() {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    // Open database
    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    if( rc ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return ;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    /* Create table statement */
    const char *sql = "CREATE TABLE TEST("  \
    "ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," \
    "NAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL," \
    "PASSWORD CHAR(50) NOT NULL);";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success\n");
    }

    // Insert test data
    sql = "INSERT INTO TEST(ID, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES(1, \"PETER\", \"ORANGE\");";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success\n");
    }


    // Allocate space for the structure
    struct Usuario *u = (struct Usuario *)malloc(sizeof(struct Usuario));

    sql = "SELECT * FROM TEST";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, u, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Success\n");
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);

    printf("Hi my name is: %s with password of %s\n", u->name, u->password);
}

int main() {
    bd_sacarDatosUsuario();

}
```

Change the structure according to your needs. Note that you should check if malloc returns a non-NULL value and of course deallocate it after you do not need that.